# Why GridView page navigation is fast in Modal Popup Extender?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a GridView control on a web page which shows around fifty pages (10 rows on each page). During navigation, from one page to another, the GridView slowly loads records. The page navigation is slow.

I tried putting this GridView control inside Ajax Control Toolkit's Modal Popup Extender. The page navigation is faster when GridView is inside Modal Popup Extender.

Is it just a coincidence or any other reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Ajax Control Toolkit's Modal Popup Extender uses the Script Manager and Update Panel
by which the partial page is rendered 
and on your plain page you have Script Manager and Update Panel so your page is rendered on pagination next and previous.

so if you want to make your grid view faster on plain page then use update panel which will reload partial page.

Comment: I do have an Update Panel on page itself.

Comment: Then there is no reason it depend on the design pattern of your this page . mostly speed depend on the design